# Javascript removendo números zero no início de uma string

Tags: javascript

Senhores(as)

Eu tenho uma função que desvincula uma inscrição pelo cpf, porém, quando eu passo um valor que inicia com zero por parâmetro os números são removidos. Já tentei praticamente de tudo para resolver o problema, quando realizo buscas referente a este assunto, basicamente eu só encontro como **remover** os zeros e não manter.

O input que estou armazenando o cpf é do tipo "text".

Código no html

```
 <button title="Deletar Inscrição" type="button" onclick="$('#ModalConfirmacao').modal('toggle');
                                            $('#CpfSelecionado').val(@item.Inscricao.cpf_candidato);
                                            $('#CursoSelecionado').val(@item.Inscricao.cd_curso);
                                            $('#EdicaoSelecionada').val(@item.Inscricao.cd_edicao);">
                                                    <span class="fa fa-remove"></span>
                                                </button>
```

Código js

```
function DesvincularInscricaoNovo() {
    var cpf = document.getElementById('CpfSelecionado').value;
    var curso = document.getElementById('CursoSelecionado').value;
    var edicao = document.getElementById('EdicaoSelecionada').value;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: urlPortal + 'DesvincularInscricao?cpf=' + cpf +
            "&cursoId=" + curso +
            "&edicaoId=" + edicao,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            if (!data.Error) {
                $('#ModalSucesso').modal('toggle');
                $('#textModal').empty().text(data.Mensagem);
                //document.getElementById('inscricoesBody').deleteRow(document.getElementById('Cliquei').value);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Parâmetro passado: 00885355849

Valor retornado na função: 885355849

Comment: Você quer uma resposta ou quer um chute. Se quiser uma resposta coloque o elemento cujo o `id` é `CpfSelecionado` e todo código relacionado a ele(eventos, validação, formatação, máscara,...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema é que você está passando o CPF direto como número no `.val()`. Assim, os zeros à esquerda serão ignorados.

Supondo que `@item.Inscricao.cpf_candidato` seja `00885355849`, então o jQuery no onclick onde você adiciona o valor no input seria:

```
$('#CpfSelecionado').val(00885355849);
```

Porém, como você está passando um valor puramente numérico no `.val()`, os zeros à esquerda serão ignorados e irá adicionar apenas `885355849` no input.

O correto seria que o valor seja uma string, ou seja, entre aspas, assim:

```
$('#CpfSelecionado').val('00885355849');
```

Então, para resolver o problema, basta colocar `@item.Inscricao.cpf_candidato` entre aspas:

```
$('#CpfSelecionado').val('@item.Inscricao.cpf_candidato');
                         ↑                             ↑
```

Comment: Excelente! Consegui resolver, muito obrigado Sam!

Comment: Bom q resolveu. Agora é só marcar a resposta acima. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Isso acontece porque o JS ignora os zeros a esquerda caso o tipo seja number, tente mudar para string, e veja se consiga usar dessa forma. Caso precise usar o tipo number, você pode usar o parseInt()

Aqui está um link que possa te ajudar!

https://flaviocopes.com/how-to-trim-leading-zero-number/

Comment: Já tentei utilizar tipo text e number, porém continuo com o mesmo problema. Obrigado pelo link.